# Printing several student's data in several pages in laravel

Tags: laravel, printing

I am working on a Laravel application where I have $students variable with lots of students with their details. A Student's data may need 1 or more pages. I have to print them by one click in several pages with separate pages. How to do this?

There are lots of students, and taking too long to load when trying to print from browser using ctrl+p. Most importantly the next students data in not starting from a new page.

Comment: You need to print them from browser window, or you need to print them in general?

Comment: There are lots of students, and taking too long to load when trying to print from browser using ctrl+p. Most importantly the next students data in not starting from a new page.

Comment: How many students do you have to print?

Comment: about one thousand